# C program originally written in Linux, now porting to Windows using Cygwin (compile w/ gcc)

Tags: linux, gcc, cygwin

I'm working on a fairly lengthy project that was originally written in C on a Linux machine.  I need to port it to windows and am trying to use the gcc compiler in Cygwin as the "easiest" method of transfer.

The program was originally written a long time ago and has been through many hands.  It has always been run on Linux before and has had no problems.  There are a number of parts to the program most of which compile and run fine under both Linux and Cygwin.  However, there is one portion of the project which compiles in Cygwin but gives a segmentation fault before doing anything as far as I can tell (same code works fine in Linux).

I've put in a number of printf() statements to see if I can narrow it down but it seems to give the seg fault before it does anything at all (i.e., my first printf() is the first thing after main(){...).  I've used the -Wall option with gcc to try and see if there are any "obvious" warnings/errors but don't see anything that jumps out.  They're mostly just warnings about expecting "int" when a "long int" is passed but these are identical to the warnings I get using -Wall in Linux as well.

Does anyone have a suggestion on what kinds of things I should look for in trying to make the code compatible for Cygwin and/or thoughts on what might be causing the code to give a seg fault before even getting going in Cygwin?  (I'd post some code but it's several thousand lines).

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
Thanks for the suggestions. I went through the gdb with results shown below. I then spent the better part of yesterday trying MinGW in Linux. Still with no success. Could either/both problems have something to do with the architecture (Sandy Bridge) or the OS (Windows 7 64 bit)??  I get a seg fault as soon as the program loads - it doesn't even make it past main(...)

Comment: Have you installed gdb (or some other debugger) in your Cygwin environment and ran the program under the debugger to see exactly where it crashed?

Comment: What DLLs are the program linked to? Is C++ involved (static initializers might be involved in the problem). Does anything jump out when you run the program under gdb or cdb (from the "Debugging Tools for Windows" package, which is part of the Windows SDK now)?

Comment: I'm using: #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "time.h"
#include <unistd.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

Comment: Running gdb I get:`code`[New thread 4180.0x1310] \\
Error: dll starting at 0x76b90000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x76150000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x76b90000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x76a90000 not found.
[New thread 4180.0xb34]

Comment: ...followed by: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_alloca ()
    at /gnu/gcc/releases/respins/4.3.4-4/gcc4-4.3.4-4/src/gcc-4.3.4/libgcc/../gcc/config/i386/cygwin.asm:55
55      /gnu/gcc/releases/respins/4.3.4-4/gcc4-4.3.4-4/src/gcc-4.3.4/libgcc/../gcc/config/i386/cygwin.asm: No such file or directory.
        in /gnu/gcc/releases/respins/4.3.4-4/gcc4-4.3.4-4/src/gcc-4.3.4/libgcc/../gcc/config/i386/cygwin.asm
Current language:  auto; currently asm

Comment: Using backtrace I get: (gdb) backtrace
#0  _alloca ()
    at /gnu/gcc/releases/respins/4.3.4-4/gcc4-4.3.4-4/src/gcc-4.3.4/libgcc/../gcc/config/i386/cygwin.asm:55
#1  0x0040119a in main (argc=Cannot access memory at address 0xffe334ec
) at groundBasedTmp.c:267
 -- line 267 is the first line of main()

Comment: @Ben - you should edit that info into the question where it'll likely be more readable.  Also, can we get the compile & link command lines?

Comment: What local variables are there in `main` Any `alloca()` call? Any Variable Length Array?

Comment: @Ben - I've merged your unregistered account into your registered one. You can now edit your question, leave comments on your question and answers to it and accept an answer when the time comes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the exe in the windows environment and won't need to rebuild it there you can try using MinGW and the command `i586-mingw32msvc-g++` or `i586-mingw32msvc-gcc` in linux to cross-compile. It's worked for me; hopefully it works for you.

Comment: Running gdb I get:`code`[New thread 4180.0x1310] \\
Error: dll starting at 0x76b90000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x76150000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x76b90000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x76a90000 not found.
[New thread 4180.0xb34]